Can the Boltzmann distribution function apply to liquids?
I have been searching for ages about any way that I can calculate the kinetic energy or particle speed of liquid molecules, but all I can find are gas laws. I'm trying to calculate the probability of particle collisions between CaCO3 and HCl at average room temperature, but  can't find the average particle speed or kinetic energy in liquid particles according to temperature. Or if anyone knows of alternative methods to calculating the probability of collisions that would be great!

Your answer (for complex molecules) is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/329168/226902 (reference: "Understanding Molecular Simulations" by Frenkel and Smit, see also Landau's general derivation of MB distribution).

Moreover, MB distribution arses from the detailed balance property at equilibrium, see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/745726/226902

Awesome, thank you
